# Collecting callstack from debugee?

Tags: debugging, x86, callstack

I am currently making a debugger in my spare time. Mainly it is suppouse to have functionality similar to what Ollydbg has to offer. I am only insterested in supporting Windows x86.

I am trying to find a way to show the callstack from the debugee. I am looking for suggestions on how I should collect information about the debugee's callstack?

Comment: Seems like I have done a poorly research. Minutes after posting this question I came over this codeproject article:

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11132/Walking-the-callstack